# Use Adobe Creative SDk in Kendo UI Mobile Application

Tags: adobecreativesdk

Is it possible to implement adobe creative inside Kendo UI mobile application? if possible please send tutorial link. my requirement is let the user modify the camera captured picture before they upload it on our application.